# How to Rollback OnetoOne Relationship in Spring JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I Have Three Entity Classes while I'm Inserting Data into Database If Any Exception is Thrown then All table Values are Should be Rollback

Service Class:

```
    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class CustomerService  {
    
        private final CustomerDetailsRepo cdRepo;
        
        @Autowired
        public CustomerService(CustomerDetailsRepo cdRepo) {
            
            this.cdRepo = cdRepo;
            
        }
        public void saveCustomer(CustomerDetails customerDetails) 
        {   
            cdRepo.save(customerDetails);       
        }   
}
```

The Above Service Class is One of my Three Service class

Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_Customer")
public class CustomerDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="Customer_Id")
    private Long custid;

    @Column(name="Customer_Name")
    private String customerName;
    
    @Column(name="Email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="Address")
    private String address;
    
    @Column(name="Phone")
    private String phoneno;
    
    public CustomerDetails() {
    }
      
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customerDetails", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;

//getters and setters
}
```

Here I'm used OnetoOne Relationship

Comment: What code have you tried? Where are you failing? This seems like a college project question

Comment: @Asgar I'm not failing anywhere now I just done insertion next I want to do rollback If any exception occurs anywhere while inserting all data's should be rollbacked but I don't know how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this.
Something like :

```
public void saveCustomer(CustomerDetails customerDetails) {
  try {
    cdRepo.save(customerDetails);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
  }
}
```

Or you can mark your method with Transactional.
Eg:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLException.class)
public void saveCustomer(CustomerDetails customerDetails) throws SQLException{   
 cdRepo.save(customerDetails);
throw new SQLException("Some error when saving");       
}
```

To learn more, you can refer [here](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring).

Comment: When I'm using rollbackFor I'm getting Error It Suggest me to change rollbackOn

Comment: Try changing it to whatever your IDE says. Maybe it has something to do with the version. I am not sure about that. But the idea for rollback is the same